# BrowserSync proxy to Homestead really slow

Tags: gulp, homestead, browser-sync

When using a proxy for BrowserSync it takes about 5-6s for requests to complete.

Gulp:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    if (argv.serve) {
        browserSync.init({
            proxy: {
                target: argv.serve,
            }
        });
    }

    gulp.watch(paths.themes.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

I have tried the suggestion on this question: [BrowserSync extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807786/browsersync-extremely-slow) but all my hosts are already setup as .dev.

I am running this locally. I have an hosts entry in /etc/hosts. Running OSX 10.10.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was an issue with my DNS.

The following gets around the issue:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    if (argv.serve) {
        browserSync.init({
            proxy: {
                target: "192.168.10.10",
                reqHeaders: function (config) {
                    return {
                        "host": argv.serve,
                    }
                },
            }
        });
    }

    gulp.watch(paths.themes.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

Skipping the need to resolve host.