# Webpack with BrowserSync reloading extremely slowly

Tags: javascript, webpack, browser-sync

I typically develop React apps but due to some client concerns I am having to develop a site for them on top of Wordpress. There are some very dynamic portions of the site, so I decided to implement webpack so that I enjoy some of the luxuries of a modern framework along the way. And it's working great. With the exception of the fact that it can take around 10 seconds for a BrowserSync live reload to complete.

Granted, I'm new to webpack, so I'm sure I'm missing something. I know that with React in the past I have used webpack-dev-server with HMR. And here I am using BrowserSync, a la this tutorial: https://www.kirstencassidy.com/incorporting-webpack-wordpress-theme-part-2/

I've implemented things like hardsource plugin and cache-loader to try to speed things up. And I've followed the suggestions offered here: [BrowserSync extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807786/browsersync-extremely-slow) having to do with IPv6 proxying and adding ::1 [site].com.test entries to /etc/hosts. But nothing seems to help speed things up.

webpack.config.js:

```html
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')
const HardsourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin')
const config = require('./config')

module.exports = function(env) {
  return  {
    entry: {
      main: "./js/index.js",
      home: "./js/components/pages/home.js",
      connect: "./js/components/pages/connect/index.js",
      learn: "./js/components/pages/learn/index.js",
      community: "./js/components/pages/learn/community.js",
      founders: "./js/components/pages/learn/founders.js"
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist"),
      filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "cache-loader"
            },
            {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: ["env"]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "cache-loader"
            },
            {
              loader: "raw-loader"
            }
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: [
              {
                loader: "cache-loader"
              },
              {
                loader: "css-loader"
              },
              {
                loader: "sass-loader"
              }
            ]
          }),
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: [
            'file-loader'
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      compress: true,
      port: 3001,
      https: config.url.indexOf('https') > -1 ? true : false,
      publicPath: config.fullPath,
      proxy: {
        '*': {
          'target': config.url,
          'secure': false
        },
        '/': {
          target: config.url,
          secure: false
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new HardsourceWebpackPlugin(),
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'styles/[name].css',
        allChunks: true
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'common'
      }),
      // new UglifyJsPlugin({
      //   sourceMap: true,
      //   uglifyOptions: {
      //     ie8: false,
      //     ecma: 8,
      //     mangle: true,
      //     output: {
      //       comments: false,
      //       beautify: false
      //     },
      //     warnings: false
      //   }
      // }),
      new BrowserSyncPlugin({
        proxy: config.url,
        files: [
          '**/*.php'
        ],
        reloadDelay: 0,
        online: true
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

config.js:

```html
module.exports = {
  url: 'http://fakewebsite.com.test/',
  themeDir: '/wp-content/themes/CGO/',
  fullPath: 'http://fakewebsite.com.test/wp-content/themes/CGO/',
  ip: '127.0.0.1'
}
```

and here's a screenshot of cli log if this gives anyone some clues:

[image]

Any clue what I might be doing wrong? What can I do to speed up webpack performance? Is it just because I am compiling so many scss/js files at once? Live reloads are great but when rapid iterations are being made the 10 second interval is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, after much finicking and variable isolation, this is all actually some sort of DNS lookup delay issue, not webpack. It's strange, because this is the first time I've ever tried to proxy hot reloading from a _.com.test site to localhost, but I don't remember _.com.dev ever taking so long to reload (can't use .dev anymore because of google claiming the tld).

So that solves all that ^^^ , but if anyone has any tips for the ACTUAL issue, answers still appreciated :)